# Footer/Navbar rendering incorrectly - not fitting button in

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

Using JQM to create a mobile web app. (JQ 1.7/JQM 1.4.5)

Have a footer on a page including a navbar with a save button.

Clicking on this page renders the footer incorrectly, other pages render the footer fine. If clicking the page for the first time since load it works, but going back and clicking it again makes it fail.

```
 <div data-position="fixed" data-role="footer" data-theme="b">      
  <div> data-role="navbar">
    <ul>
       <li><a id="submitNumberRoute" data-icon="check" >Save</a></li>
     </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
```

**Incorrect rendering:**

[image: Rendering incorrectly]

**Correct rendering:**

[image: Rendering correctly]

Comment: Looking in to this more I found that after jquery has rendered the page if the footer is broken it has `style="display: inline;"` on this: 

`<li><a id="submitNumberRoute" data-icon="check" >Save</a></li>`

Answer (score 0):

Try `data-fullscreen :"true"` 
in the first div